# StackOverflowError too early

Tags: java, arrays, stack-overflow

Whenever I give the `size` of array more than `3`, my program gives me `StackOverflowError`.

```
package database;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class The_Maximum_Subarray {
    int a[];

    public The_Maximum_Subarray(int size) {
        a=new int[size];
    }

    public int maxsubArray(int[] a,int li,int ui)
    {  
        if(ui ==li)
            return a[li];

        int m=(ui-li)/2;
        int leftMaxSubarray=maxsubArray(a, li, m);
        int rightMaxSubarray=maxsubArray(a, m+1, ui);
        int leftSum=0,rightSum=0,sum=0;

        for(int i=m;i>=li;i--)
        {
            sum+=a[i];
            if(sum>leftSum)
                leftSum=sum;
        }

        sum=0;
        for(int i=m+1;i<=ui;i++)
        {
            sum+=a[i];
            if(sum>rightSum)
                rightSum=sum;
        }
        sum=leftSum+rightSum;

        if(rightMaxSubarray>=leftMaxSubarray && rightMaxSubarray>=sum)
            return rightSum;
        else if(leftMaxSubarray>=rightMaxSubarray && leftMaxSubarray>=sum)
            return leftSum;
        else
            return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);   
        int size=sc.nextInt();
        The_Maximum_Subarray obj=new The_Maximum_Subarray(size);

         for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
             obj.a[j]=sc.nextInt(); 
         System.out.println(obj.maxsubArray(obj.a, 0, size-1)); 
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it's giving me this exception for this small size array ?

Comment: Because you have an infinitely deep recursion, set a breakpoint and debug your code, step through the `maxsubArray` line by line.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html)

Comment: You appear to be using a combination of recursion and loops. Also you can do this much more efficiently if you start with an array of all the sums up to a given point and find the greatest difference between two values.

Comment: BTW You can do this in a single pass loop without recursion. I would think about how you can simplify this.  It's not quick sort or merge sort which this appears to be based on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,this was actually kadanes algo..the mistake in my code was in the line  'int m=(ui-li)/2;' it should be 'int m=(ui-li)/2+li;'

Answer (score 1):

From your question:

> Can anyone tell me why its giving me this exception for this small size array ?

For the part `Why it is causing??`

According to the `java` language specifications for `java.lang.StackOverflowError`, this error occurs when an application recurses too deeply.

This recursion results in filling the stack and it tries to exceed the limit of the stack which is `Xs`.

Take a simple example:

```
class StackOverflowDemo {
    private void causeOverflow(int i) {
        causeOverflow(i);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StackOverflowDemo demo =  new StackOverflowDemo();
        demo.causeOverflow(5);
    }
}
```

Here, the `System.out.println(i)` will be called recursively i.e it will be pushed to the stack when it is called.